# How can I get the label for a scroll view in a Xcode 7.2 XCTestCase?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode7.2

In XCode 7.2, if I can get XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Foo"].otherElements.otherElements["Page Title"], what's the way to say, "Give me the page title for this scrollView named "Foo"?"

I have tried asking for the accessibilityLabel and staticTexts.

I have tried adding XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Foo"], XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Foo"].otherElements, etc to my watch list but I don't see any useful information.

When I do a `po` on `XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Foo"].otherElements`, I get:

```
<snip>
↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Other
Output: {
      Other 0x7f904b60e910: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}, label: 'PDF article'
      Other 0x7f9049efb6e0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
    }
```

(Page title in this case is 'PDF article')

So I feel like I should be able to access it with staticTexts at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your page title is a custom view that doesn't inherit from UILabel (UILabel descendants are marked as StaticTexts).

You need to set an accessibility *identifier* (not label) on your page title in the app's code.

```
pageTitle.accessibilityIdentifier = "Page Title"
```

This should make your code work and would be the best practice.

Alternatively, if you change your search chain to use the value of the label instead of `"Page Title"`, that should work too. However, if you open a different page with a different title, this won't work.

```
XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Foo"].otherElements["PDF article"]
```